# Cosine Rule Question

Tags: trigonometry

I'm a year 11 student doing Maths B, and I'm just checking to see if my answer is correct, because the one in the notebook is different to mine. The notebook sometimes has been wrong.

Anyway, the question is this:

A plane flies in the direction of N$70$ degrees E, for $80$ KM, then on a bearing of S$10$ degrees W, for $150$ KM. How far is the plane from its starting point?

You're supposed to use cosine to find the answer.

After using cosine, I received the answer, $157.27$ Km, but the notebooks answer was $130$ Km.

Could you please solve the maths problem and tell me your answer.

If it's the same answer in the notebook, could you tell me what you done to get that answer?

Thanks!

Comment: I get the notebooks answer.  The included angle is 60 degrees.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Can I ask how you got that answer?

Comment: I'll add explanation to my answer below...

Comment: I added a couple angles to my diagram.

Comment: Thanks man, you were a real help! I forgot to add the 2 angles and subtract it from 90 to get my second angle. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

The trip should look something like this.  Is this what you had?  Included angle in your cosine calculation should be 60 degrees.

**EDIT**:  So, the first leg takes off at 70 degrees east of North.  So that means it makes an angle of 20 degrees with the x-axis.  Which means that the angle of this leg with a vertical line down from $A$ is 70 degrees.

Then, the second leg takes off 10 degrees West of South.  Since the angle straight down(South) from $A$ was 70 degrees, the angle of the line 10 degrees West of that is 60 degrees.

[image]